# differences between .sage and .spyx in numerical evaluation

Tags: sage

the question seems very basic, i'm sorry but i could not find an answer in the documentation.

the content of both files `test.sage` and `test.spyx` is identical; it's just

```
a = 1/sqrt(2)
print a
```

if i run `test.sage` with

```
$ sage test.sage
```

i get

```
1/2*sqrt(2)
```

but the outcome is different from if i run the file `test.spyx` with

```
$ sage test.spyx
```

where i get

```
Compiling test.spyx...
0.707106781187
```

how can i prevent sage from numerically evaluating `1/\sqrt(2)` in `.spyx` mode?

(i asked the question on [ask.sagemath.org](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/37103/differences-between-sage-and-spyx-in-numerical-evaluation/) as well but got no answer yet...)

Comment: Ordinarily `from sage.all import *` should do the job but it doesn't.